# How to print a linebreak in a python function?

Tags: python, line-breaks

I have a list of strings in my code;

```
A = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3' ...]
B = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3' ...]
```

and I want to print them separated by a linebreak, like this:

```
>a1
b1
>a2
b2
>a3
b3
```

I've tried:

```
print '>' + A + '/n' + B
```

But /n isn't recognized like a line break.

Comment: Use `\n`. That was the issue

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You have your slash backwards, it should be `"\n"`

Comment: Backward slash = "\" , forward slash = "/". The OP has his slash forwards.

Comment: @user3527975, I mean backwards in the sense of reversed from how it should be.

Comment: since there is some confusion: @Geparda use the other slash :)

Comment: @WinstonEwert Don't you think you should rephrase it to avoid the confusion, instead of leaving it as is?

Comment: @LucaBezerra, there isn't any evidence that anyone was confused, just that some people are pedantic.

Comment: @WinstonEwert Given that there are 8 upvotes for comments mentioning that it could be confusing, I beg to disagree. Since this is a Python-related question, I'll quote a couple of verses from the Zen of Python: "Readability counts. In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess". Even if you disagree that it's ambiguous, I don't see what's the big deal in editing it for the sake of everyone understanding it clearly. But maybe you're right and some people are just pedantic :)

Comment: @LucaBezerra, given that my answer has 178 upvotes, I'd say most people found it clear. Regardless, you can edit any answer on here that you think can be improved, feel free.

Comment: @WinstonEwert Your comment was whether **anyone** was confused, not the majority of people. Indeed, I could edit it, but I won't do it if I explicitly know that it doesn't reflect the author's intent. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Ok, people, how do I have hundreds of upvotes for this?

Comment: Clearly it's more than 6 times better than zeekay's answer.

Comment: @LucaBezerra since you seem to care about precision: There would have been a problem if he wrote "you have a backward slash". "You have your slash backwards" conveys perfectly correctly in terms of grammar the fact that the opposite direction of slash with respect to that of the OP should be used. Very strictly speaking, you have it wrong in terms of grammar and Winston Ewert has it right.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment as it was not written in the most appropriate way for a healthy community, I apologize for that.
@Helen I never said his grammar was wrong, I said it was noticeably confusing for some people and he could make it less confusing. Being grammar-correct doesn't mean it's the best way to communicate an idea. But I will not elongate this discussion any further, as it doesn't add anything to the topic. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 37):

The newline character is actually `'\n'`.

Answer (score 12):

All three way you can use for newline character :

```
'\n'

"\n"

"""\n"""
```

Comment: `"\x0a"` ``````

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> A = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
>>> B = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']

>>> for x in A:
        for i in B:
            print ">" + x + "\n" + i
```

Outputs:

```
>a1
b1
>a1
b2
>a1
b3
>a2
b1
>a2
b2
>a2
b3
>a3
b1
>a3
b2
>a3
b3
```

Notice that you are using `/n` which is **not** correct!

Answer (score 10):

```
for pair in zip(A, B):
    print ">"+'\n'.join(pair)
```

Answer (score 2):

`\n` is an escape sequence, denoted by the backslash. A normal forward slash, such as `/n` will not do the job. In your code you are using `/n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

You can print a native linebreak using the standard `os` library

```
import os
with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(os.linesep)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also if you're making it a console program, you can do: `print(" ")` and continue your program. I've found it the easiest way to separate my text.

Answer (score 1):

```py
A = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'] 
B = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
for a,b in zip(A,B): 
    print(f">{a}\n{b}")
```

Below `python 3.6` instead of `print(f">{a}\n{b}")` use `print(">%s\n%s" % (a, b))`