# How to get new line

Tags: python

How can I print a new line on the output file?
 When I try to add the new line with "/n" it just prints /n

This is what I have so far.

``
inputFile = open("demofile1.txt", "r")
outFile = open("Ji

```
    string = line.split(',')

    go =(string)[3::]
    bo = [float(i) for i in go]
    total = sum(bo)
    pine = ("%8.2f"%total)
    name = string[2] + "," + " " + string[1]

    kale = (string[0] + " " + name + " " + "/n")

    se)
```

Current Result

```
8 
53 Baul 
A999999
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a linebreak in a python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982206/how-to-print-a-linebreak-in-a-python-function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `\n`, not `/n`. So this line:

```
kale = (string[0] + " " + name + " " + "/n")
```

Should be:

```
kale = (string[0] + " " + name + " " + "\n")
```

Also, please do consider using a `str` formatter, so all these lines:

```
go =(string)[3::]
bo = [float(i) for i in go]
total = sum(bo)
pine = ("%8.2f"%total)
name = string[2] + "," + " " + string[1]
kale = (string[0] + " " + name + " " + "/n")
str1 = ''.join(kale)
str2 = ''.join(pine)
outFile.write(str1 + " " + str2 + " ")
```

Will become:

```
outFile.write("{} {} {:8.2f}\n".format(string[0], string[2] + ", " + string[1], sum(bo))
```